# Designing UI for a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a plugin for Google chrome that works similarly to the Adobe's web-capture plugin for Mozilla Firefox. I need some help designing the UI for the extension. As of now, the extension has a button, next to the wrench icon, that, when clicked, converts the page to a PDF file. I need to add a drop-down menu, just as it is on Firefox, which should display other options for conversion, and providing the same functions in context menu as well. I'm not sure if it's possible to have a main button and a drop-down menu button, where the main button initiates conversion directly, and the drop-down menu button shows the drop down menu showing other options, in Google Chrome as nothing is mentioned about it's possibility on the Chrome Extension development page. I could probably have a pop-up page but that would come up when I would click the main button. Could someone help me with this? If it is possible to have a both main button, and a drop-down menu button, then how should I go about doing it? Or if it is that I would have to use a pop-up page to show the options, then where should I place my functions, which will be used by context menu APIs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand i wouldn't prefer having 2 buttons. What you can do is, have a drop down button and once that appears after clicking, you can have a big button inside that saying "PDFy my current page" and below you can have rest of the options. I guess having two button will unnecessarily bring confusion and will make browser cluttered.

Comment: Ive seen mentioned somewhere that Chrome doesnt want people adding more than one button which is why thats all you can do per extension.  So Rajshekhar's suggestion really is the right one and two clicks aint that bad ;).  As to where to put your functions...well if your doing context menu stuff then its going to be in the background page, your browser action can get accesse to the background page and execute functions from it using `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage